# Error caused when set checkboxes as checked using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the html:

```
<span ng-repeat="category in categories">
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="{{category.id}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="check(category.id)" ng-click="saveRoleMenu($event,category.id)" name="group" id="{{category.id}}" />
        {{category.name}}
      </label>
</span>
```

this is my controller:

```
//get all the menus
authorityService.getMenus().then(function(response) {
    $scope.categories = response.data.data; //get all the menus success
})

//get the user's menus
var roleId = sessionStorage.getItem("roleId");
authorityService.getMenusByRoleId(roleId).then(function(response) {
    $scope.userMenu = response.data.data; //get the user's menu success
})
$scope.saveRoleMenu = function($event, id) {
    var checkbox = $event.target;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        var roleId = $location.search().id;
        authorityService.saveRoleMenu(roleId, id).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.code == 0) {
                alert("success！");
            }
        })
    }
}

$scope.check = function(value) {
    //error caused here
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.userMenu.length; i++) {
        if(value == $scope.userMenu[i].id){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set checkbox checked if the value in `$scope.userMenu`,but in the check function,caused the error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined",what's the reason about this error?

Comment: @SarjanDesai only this: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

means `$scope.userMenu` is not defined. **Define $scope.userMenu before assigning value to it.**

```
$scope.userMenu = [];
var roleId = sessionStorage.getItem("roleId");
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because your `userMenu` are loaded from API and the `check` function execute before they are loaded.

define the `userMenu` in top something like this -

```
$scope.userMenu = [];
```

This would stop `check` from throwing errors. Once menu are loaded from API view will re-render with it.